# Checking multi columns in 'in' clause

Tags: hibernate

How can i achieve the following query in hibernate---

```
select * from wf_inbox_v where target_user='some value' and 111 in (id,rev_ref_id)
```

the 111 is constant value.

Please Help me

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple query if needed as below.

If I assume the bean name is `WfInboxV` as:

```
public class WfInboxV {
    private String targetUser;
    private int id;
    private int revRefId;
}
```

Then the query will be:

```
String query = "from WfInboxV where targetUser='some value' and '111' in (id,revRefId)";
Query query = session.createQuery(query);
List list = query.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is you looking for BUT CHECK THIS

```
select * from wf_inbox_v where target_user='some value' and (id= 111 or rev_ref_id = 111)
```